# using pselect() with completion structure?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, shared-memory

I have a Multi-core system and the other core sends me the signal as a form of a pointer to struct completion.
but my code on the other core is working with `Pselect()` function, so can I check the same signal with that `Pselect()` function? or how can I receive that signal?
sorry, I'm a beginner in the embedded Linux programming and I tried to read a lot to know how to make this communication.

Comment: `sends me the signal as a form of a pointer to struct completion` A signal doesn't have a "form", it's just a number. What "struct completion" are you referring? Could you post some example code?

Comment: this for example
https://cpp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/wait_for_completion_interruptible/cpp-wait_for_completion_interruptible-function-examples.html
are many examples which all of them waiting for 
 a pointer to struct completion ex: wait_for_completion_interruptible(&io_comp);
So actually i will receive somehting similar to (&io_comp) from the other core. i just want to replace (wait_for_completion_interruptible function) with pselect()

Comment: This looks like kernel code. Are you programming in kernel? Please explain your environment in more detail.. There is no `pselect()` in kernel, `pselect()` is a user-space function.

Comment: i have 2 cores. i dont program in kenrnel. i need to make commnication between that 2 cores using shared memory. i found that the other core using that kernel code to send something. for my side i want to receive what is sent to me from that core using pselect (im running linux ubuntu)